# What is the variation of $(-1)^n$

Tags: sequences-and-series

I just wanted to know what the variation of $U_n = (-1)^n$ is. I think it is constant but the regular methods do not work. Since $U_{n+1} - U_n$ is either negative (which means $U$ is descending) or equal to 0 (which means $U$ is constant). Furthermore, $\frac{U_{n+1}}{U_n} < 0$ which shouldn't be possible. In my understanding you cannot convert this sequence in a function and study the variation of this function. If you could enlighten me on this...

Comment: How do you define the variation of a sequence?

Comment: Who knows what you want to do with it, but (total) variation normally adds the absolute values of the changes: $\sum_n |U_{n+1}-U_n|$.